# Implementing Haskell-style pattern matching with type checking

Tags: haskell, clojure, pattern-matching

I am working on a project to recreate some of the features of Haskell in Clojure. I have succeeded in implementing Hindley-Milner type inference, and now I am trying to introduce pattern-matching syntax via a macro. My goal is to have the macro first emit valid Clojure code and then type-check that code, but I am finding this hard to do. Since I'm brand new to Haskell and static typing in general, I'm not sure if there's a way to do it that I don't see, or whether it's just not possible.

I'm attempting to follow [Luc Maranget's algorithm](http://moscova.inria.fr/~maranget/papers/ml05e-maranget.pdf), at least the naive version for now. My understanding is that you take a vector of values (or "occurrences" at compile time) and treat it as a stack. After grouping the rows of patterns by the constructors of the first column, you find the group of patterns corresponding to the constructor of the first value in the vector. If the vector is `(v1 ... vn)`, and `v1` is `c(a1 ... ak)`, where `c` is the constructor and `a1 ... ak` are the arguments to the constructor, then you drop the constructor `c` and concatenate the arguments with the vector, creating the new vector `(a1 ... ak v2 ... vn)`, and run the algorithm recursively.

My question is, how do you represent such a vector or stack in a type-checkable way? Again, my goal is for the Clojure macro to emit code that is both ready to handle runtime values but also ready to be type-checked at compile time. I could introduce an intermediate step, wherein the first macro emits code that is type-checkable but is also itself a macro, and then have the second macro emit the code that will actually run. But even if that works, it's less satisfying because it suggests that I wouldn't be able to accomplish a task like this in Haskell itself. Am I missing something?

**-- EDIT --**

I now see that my confusion arose from not having encountered a situation in my short experience with static typing in which I had to deal with a heterogeneous collection. My question could have been formulated more clearly, but since I'm mapping out the problem space as I go along, I am not always sure exactly what an obstacle is or how it's related to everything else I'm dealing with.  Thanks to the comments below, I believe that to surmount this particular challenge I just need to have a better understanding of the options available for dealing with heterogeneous collections in Haskell. [This article](https://wiki.haskell.org/Heterogenous_collections) seems to be a good starting point.

Comment: There is a lot of prior art on this topic. Have you looked at, say, core.match or core.typed to see how they address pattern-matching and type-checking? If not, you should start there.

Comment: Does core.match emit a decision tree that's both type-checkable and ready to evaluate values at runtime? Part of my objective here is to understand Haskell better. If someone were trying to do this in Haskell, they wouldn't have the option of circumventing the type system. So how would they implement this algorithm?

Comment: What makes you think that Haskell type checks and emits running code in precisely the same representation? The Haskell code which actually runs is basically C (a dialect of C called Cmm). The Haskell code which is typechecked is the concrete syntax after expansion of `type`s and such. In the middle, Haskell code spends its time mainly as core, which is similar to the concrete syntax, but no syntactic sugar and a few other features which make it amenable for program transformations. I suggest you read about GHCs actual typechecker before making assertions about what can and can't be done.

Comment: Finally, the question "how do you represent such a vector or stack in a type-checkable way?" seems entirely out of context. You represent such a vector with... a vector. That's it. There is nothing special about your typechecker other than that there is an eventual code generation step which emits code in precisely the language in which the typechecker is written. That code generation step is *entirely seperate* from the steps which involve typechecking. So your idea to have an intermediate step is perfectly sound, and is indeed what is done in a host of compilers of statically typed languages

Comment: Thanks. I have no theoretical background, so when I hit an obstacle, I don't know whether it's a theoretical one or just something I'm missing. I am aware that Haskell is compiled in C, but surely you can build a compiler in Haskell if you want to. In regards to Maranget's algorithm and vectors, I'm used to dynamically-typed languages, where it's easy to work with a vector that holds anything you want, and Maranget seems to be taking such a loose approach, but it's not clear to me how you would represent such a vector in Haskell.

Comment: In other words, Haskell has vectors, but all the elements have to be of the same type. That's not the case with Maranget's vectors.

Comment: In dynamic languages, you work with the vector assuming it contains values of a single 'type', and if it doesn't, an error happens. Sometimes, that single type is one of `k` types; that doesn't change the fact that it is morally a 'single' type. In Haskell, this is the `Either` type, or more generally, sum types. (But why ask about Haskell when you're implementing this in clojure? again; I'm not sure what the actual question here is).

Comment: That I'm doing this in Clojure is just a detail. I'm really trying to understanding Haskell through a hands-on approach. It's not really important that I'm implementing pattern-matching, either, I just wanted to give all the background. The main issue is that I've encountered a problem that I don't know how to solve without circumventing typing, which means I wouldn't be able to solve it in Haskell, so I've found something that I need to understand better. I'm familiar with Either and sum types, but I'll have to put some thought into how they help me with this quandary. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your intent, but if your goal is to understand how to solve something like this in Haskell rather than in Clojure, why are you using Clojure to write it? Why not just write it in Haskell instead?

Comment: Long story, but I get your point!